# Linux Mint showing a lot of interfaces after test Docker

Tags: networking, linux-mint

I installed and tested Docker in my linux mint computer, after that it creates a lot of network interfaces that I can't remove now, someone knows a way to remove this interfaces?

[image: Print of the network manager]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To com­pletely unin­stall docker, run the fol­low­ing com­mands.

```
sudo apt-get purge docker-engine
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge docker-engine
rm -rf /var/lib/docker # This deletes all images, containers, and volumes
```

[source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/)